# Error updating Foursquare Icons and Images

Tags: image, upload, icons, foursquare

On Foursquare Developers, I've been trying to upload icons and images to my app to no avail, I keep getting a server-side error.

I've tried changing image formats, other browsers, and giving it a couple days, but I keep getting the same error.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (__uploadappicon, line 0)
```

Any clues?